# forEach Array Method returning only the last element of the array

Tags: javascript, dom, foreach, append

I am getting each form detail from local storage to render them using the forEach array method, I am only getting the last iteration of the forEach loop.But when i console.log the array i find them all correctly.

Comment: Please include your code so we can see exactly what's going on. But to start, `forEach` doesn't return anything; it simply loops.

Comment: Your question is unclear but you can follow this easy example to run forEach loop



const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));

Answer (score -1):

When you loop through an array, make sure you also append within the loop.

Hope this helps!